# It is expected that the check subcommand of cnosdb can be optimized

Tags: cnosdb

A clear and concise description of what the problem is. Ex. I'm always frustrated when [...]
After the key in the configuration file is modified, the check subcommand cannot detect it.as follow:
[image]

Comment: "A clear and concise description of what the problem is" is an instruction for when you write your question, not an example of text you should include in the question. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).